# How to find earliest and latest event dates for particular EventId?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I need to write a query that calculates the difference (measured in days) between the earliest and latest event dates of the event with EventId "AAA".

So, it means that I should identify earliest and latest event dates for EventId.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `stats` aggregation on the date field, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "EventId": "AAA"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "minmax": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "dateField"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get a response with the min date and max date fo all documents matching the query.

Comment: How can I get hours between min and max date in one step?

Comment: @Sree please create a new question to explain your need.

Comment: Created new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183915/how-to-get-hours-between-min-and-max-date-in-elasticsearch-aggregation   Could you pls help?